# rails : Routing Error - No route matches [GET] "/posts/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a simple CRUD and get this trouble with the create method.

**Error**

No route matches [POST] "/usuarios/new"

this is my controller:

**Controller**

```
    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

def index

     @articles = Article.all

  end

def show

      @article = Article.find(params[:id])

  end

def new

  @article = Article.new

end

def create

  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save

    redirect_to @article

  else

    render 'new'

  end

end

private

  def article_params

    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)

  end
```

my new.html.reb file :

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :article do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

my routes.rb file :

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  resources :articles
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

anybody can help me?

Comment: Your title, error and the content doesn't each other. Please post the right content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most part of your post is redundant in this context. Seems like you try to call `new_usarios_path`, but in this case you must define this route in your `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :usarios
```